# Equivalence of different properties

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Show that the following are equivalent:

(i) $E$ is Lebesgue measurable ;

(ii) $|I| \geq m(I \cap E)+m(I \backslash E)$ forall interval  $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ of finite lenght;

(iii) $E \cap[n, n+1)$ is measurable forall $n \in \mathbb{Z}$;

(iv) $m([n, n+1) \cap E)+m([n, n+1) \backslash E)=1$ forall $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

There is only one thing I have to show: (iv) implies (ii), because I have shown that i) and ii) are equivalent. I was thinking about that if (iv) is true for all $n$ if I replace $[n, n+1)$ with  $I=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}([n, n+1)\cap I)$ and I write 1 as $[n, n+1)$ is still right and I have the result? Are there other ways?

Comment: According to what you said you showed that (i) $\iff$ (ii) and want to show that (iv) $\implies$ (ii).  This is not enough to show that the 4 statements are equivalent. The right way (most convenient) to do it is by showing that (i) $\implies$ (ii) $\implies$ (iii) $\implies$ (iv) $\implies$ (i). You can do that in any order you want as long as it is a closed loop of implications, e.g. you can show (iii) $\implies$ (ii) $\implies$ (ii) $\implies$ (iv) $\implies$ (iii).

Comment: I have done all the loops the only thing I want to show is that  iv implies ii as I wrote, and I am asking if my opinion is correct or not

Comment: Are you sure it is **measure**, not **outer measure** in (2) and (4)? Whether the sets in (2) and (4) are assumed to be measurable will make a big difference. Another ambiguous thing of the question is that how does your textbook define outer measure (if it is indeed outer measure) and measurability? Different textbooks define them in different ways, so context is necessary.